Feature managment in Blazor WASM
Is there any resource to help me configure features in Blazor WASM project?
I know of the package from Microsoft: Microsoft.FeatureManagement.AspNetCore and
Microsoft.FeatureManagement.
I have implemented the feature management on server side which was easy and very simple to use and understand.
I have no idea about it in blazor wasm.
We have a WASM project in .net 7 and I added the nuget package Microsoft.FeatureManagement and am injecting and using the IFeatureManager throughout the application but it seems like the package is not reading the boolean from the appsettings.json file which resides in the server project, and thus all features are marked as false.
The solution I see now seems to be writing my own FeatureManager service which doesn't seem that much of a hazzle but it would be nice to have some kind of attributes or something to lock pages and/or components behind a feature flags in blazor wasm

Welcome to stackoverflow. You have to put your appsettings.json file into the wwwroot folder.

For more information check docs

To summarize:
You have to put your appsettings.json file into the wwwroot folder, otherwise client-side blazor cannot access it.
See the Docs for more detailed information.
